# Cake build single project

Tags: .net, msbuild, cakebuild

I have a solution that contains about 80 projects, I'm trying cake to automate builds.

I have two main projects into that solution, then I need to build both, Now my problem is one of those main projects references a library that contains only .resx files let's name it **MyResxProject.dll**, it compiles as library[image]

But when I try this Cake script

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ARGUMENTS
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var target = Argument("target", "Default");
var configuration = Argument("configuration", "Debug");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// SETUP / TEARDOWN
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Setup(ctx =>
{
    // Executed BEFORE the first task.
    Information("Running tasks...");
});

Teardown(ctx =>
{
    // Executed AFTER the last task.
    Information("Finished running tasks.");
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// TASKS
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Task("Default")
.Does(() => {
    Information("Hello Cake!");
});

Task("Clean")
.Does(()=>{
    CleanDirectories("**/bin/"+configuration);
    CleanDirectories("**/obj/"+configuration);
});

Task("Build")
.IsDependentOn("Clean")
.Does(()=>{
    var path = "D:\\MySlnFolder\\MyMainProject\\MyProject.csproj";
    MSBuild(path,new MSBuildSettings(){
        Configuration = configuration
    });
});
RunTarget(target);
```

It Try to compile, but shows an error related to **MyResx.dll**

**The OutputPath property is not set
 for project 'MyResxProject.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have   specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Confi
guration='Debug'  Platform=''.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration
or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [D:\MySlnFolder\MyResxProject\MyResxProject.csproj]**

As you see that project has it's own output folder.

Questions about **CAKE**

1. How can i do to build a single project and guarantee that all referenced projects  build to?.

or

2. Where to set the output for all referenced projects ?.